# Migrating from Unity, how to do Property or MethodInjection on all classes without registering them

Tags: autofac

Ok, lets first be clear that I know this is not correct way (use constructor injection). I do have a huge codebase to take care of and a refactoring is not an option right now.

I have a base class

public abstract class ServiceBase {

public IUnitOfWork  UnitOfWork {get;set;}

}

and a lot of Concrete classes that are NOT registered in the contianer.

public class ServiceScript :  ServiceBase {

}

How do I inject IUnitOfWork??

I have alot of this ServiceScript-classes that are not registred in the Container
but is  using the AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource in Autofac

In unity I did just mark my PropertyDependency with a [Dependency]-attribute and everything just works. 
It looks like StructureMap has the same way of using attributes,  but they don't have Prism/Xamarin-support, like Autofac has.

This same problem can be applied to a  ControllerX : ControllerBase in asp.net core.

I have tried to solve this with a RegistrationSource, but can't get it to work in the controller case that I tried first.

Any input??

/Peter

Comment: Have you [read the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html)?

Comment: I do not want to register all classes. I maybe missing something.

>>>I have alot of this ServiceScript-classes that are not registred in the Container but is using the AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource in Autofac<<.

Comment: You asked how to do property injection. That doc shows how. If the question is more than that ("How do I enable property injection on all classes without registering them?") maybe clarify your question and title.

Comment: Have changed the subject. Hopfully the usecase is more clear now.